# Redux Saga calls stopped returning value after React Native upgraded to 0.64.1

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

Our project had the following dependencies:

```
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
```

We decided to upgrade it to:

```
   "react": "17.0.1",
   "react-native": "0.64.1",
```

We also use

```
    "react-redux": "7.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-expire": "0.0.2",
    "redux-persist-transform-filter": "^0.0.20",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
```

After making this upgrade the `call` method in our sagas stopped working. The call actually reaches the function, the function gets executed, but the value is never returned back to the saga.

Couldn't find any errors or logs either, try catch block also doesn't catch anything, saga simply stops running.

Any ideas on what to try or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was having the storybook in navigation stack. It had no indication, errors or warnings, so we had to go through everything one by one.
I experienced the same thing even after I created a clean project like this, but I have no idea how it happened, it was just fixed when I removed the storybook from the main project.